# What are the ECS agent ports?

Tags: amazon-ecs

## Question

Which ports does the ECS agent use? [Amazon ECS Container Agent Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html) refers to ECS_RESERVED_PORTS. Are these the one which the ECS agent listens, hence need to be open in the ECS EC2 security group?

```
ECS_RESERVED_PORTS
Example values: [22, 80, 5000, 8080]

Default value on Linux: [22, 2375, 2376, 51678, 51679, 51680]

Default value on Windows: [53, 135, 139, 445, 2375, 2376, 3389, 5985, 51678, 51679]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ECS Container Agent does not require inbound ports to be open

Hence no security group inbound port configuration required for ECS Container Agent.

[AWS ECS Developer Guide - Setting Up with Amazon ECS - Create a Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ecs.html#create-a-base-security-group)

> Amazon ECS container instances **do NOT require any inbound ports to be open**. However, you might want to add an SSH rule so you can log into the container instance and examine the tasks with Docker commands. You can also add rules for HTTP and HTTPS if you want your container instance to host a task that runs a web server. Container instances do require external network access to communicate with the Amazon ECS service endpoint. Complete the following steps to add these optional security group rules.

I hope for better AWS terminologies. **ECS Container Instance** is EC2 instance, not Docker Container Instance. It can be confusing using "Container Instance" as it can be either a Docker container instance or an EC2 instance. Why not use "ECS EC2 Instance" to be specific then it would not cause any confusion. **API Gateway lambda proxy integration** and **API Gateway lambda integration** which do not give any clue about the difference between them, etc etc.

Comment: Just want to be more exact that ECS Container Agent DO NEED at least 1 outbound rule (ALL) for it works correctly. It's happen rarely if you create the rules very strictly (in my case) that does not allow any out bound rule

Answer (score 3):

These are ports that are either expected to already be used, or would cause confusion if they were reused.  You can find some of the port definitions [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/782948476da6d995ad33c6a04130f8172820af27/agent/config/config.go) and [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/782948476da6d995ad33c6a04130f8172820af27/agent/config/config_windows.go).

- 22 (Linux) - Used for SSH
- 53 (Windows) - Used by the DNS client
- 135 (Windows) - Used by Windows RPC
- 139 (Windows) - Used by NetBIOS
- 445 (Windows) - Used by SMB
- 2375, 2376 - Used for exposing the Docker API over TCP and with TLS
- 3389 (Windows) - Used by Remote Desktop
- 5985 (Windows) - Used by WinRM
- 51678, 51679, 51680 - Used by the ECS agent for various APIs